# WebStorm SCSS configuration for keeping empty lines

Tags: configuration, webstorm

How should I configure WebStorm in order to keep empty lines placed into a SCSS file? When formatting it removes them.

Comment: Can you please attach a code sample? WebStorm by default keeps 1 empty line between the block and inside the blocks.

Comment: `@import "validation";  
empty line here  
@import "dag-view";  
// sometimes css items in scss at component level are ignored  
@import "patches/patches";
` just consider you have a line per import and comment

Comment: there is no such feature; please feel free to file a request for it to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 0):

U can use `ij_scss_keep_blank_lines_in_code` option in ur .editorconfig file like that

```
[*.scss]
ij_scss_keep_blank_lines_in_code = X
```

X - is the maximum allowable amount of blank lines